# How to format notebook like ACL Papers?

Tags: notebooks, formatting, stylesheet, column

I typically use the ICML or [ACL paper format in latex which is two-columns](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/acl-2020-proceedings-template/zsrkcwjptpcd) (shown below). Is there anyway to get a two column stylesheet that looks similar?

[image]

Comment: I wrote style sheets for doing two-column notebooks many years back and it never works well. The system just isn't really designed for it

Comment: I'm sure it's hopeless, but could you post them here for ppl to poke at?

Comment: Using graphics and insets: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7138184/879601

Comment: Insets get messy

Comment: Re: "*Insets get messy*" - I use them a lot actually.  Basically making containers and filling them with text.  Where text spills into the next column (container) would be an exercise to manage.  I use paragraphs that expand to encompass the text, so I need to 'measure' how tall a justified text block will be when printed, [like so](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10065/how-to-rasterize-in-printout-style).  Including inline formulas in text would be a challenge though.